# escaped characters in comand

Tags: linux, azure, azure-cli

currently I want to create simple automation that will tag my Azure resources based on content of json file. To parse json into tags that can be used inside `az tag update` I'm using jq with command `jq -rj '. | to_entries[] |" \"\(.key)\"=\"\(.value)\""'`.
This is returning tags in a format that is consumed by AZ CLI i.e:

```
"primary_owner"="Owner Name" "primary_email"="owner@owner.com" "deplyment_version"="1.0.0" "project_epic"="" "project_feature"="" "project_name"="DIF" "project_billing_name"="DIF" "cost_center"="" "owner_email"="" "incident_management_application_id"="ServiceNow" "environment"="PROD NEW" "opco"="PROD NEW" "department_name"="DATA and ANALYTICS"
```

Problem that I'm facing right now is that when I copy-paste those tags into a command

```
az tag update --operation Replace --resource-id /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTON/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE --tags "primary_owner"="Owner Name" "primary_email"="owner@owner.com" "deplyment_version"="1.0.0" "project_epic"="" "project_feature"="" "project_name"="DIF" "project_billing_name"="DIF" "cost_center"="" "owner_email"="" "incident_management_application_id"="ServiceNow" "environment"="PROD NEW" "opco"="PROD NEW" "department_name"="DATA and ANALYTICS"
```

everything is working fine with output looking like

```
"properties": {
    "tags": {
      "cost_center": "",
      "department_name": "DATA and ANALYTICS",
      "deplyment_version": "1.0.0",
      "environment": "PROD NEW",
      "incident_management_application_id": "ServiceNow",
      "opco": "PROD NEW",
      "owner_email": "",
      "primary_email": "owner@owner.com",
      "primary_owner": "Owner Name",
      "project_billing_name": "DIF",
      "project_epic": "",
      "project_feature": "",
      "project_name": "DIF"
    }
```

However whenever I try to get them using any command i.e

```
az tag update --operation Replace --resource-id /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTON/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE --tags $(jq -rj '. | to_entries[] |" \"\(.key)\"=\"\(.value)\""'`)
```

or by running

```
jq -rj '. | to_entries[] |" \"\(.key)\"=\"\(.value)\""'` > file
az tag update --operation Replace --resource-id /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTON/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE --tags $(less file)
```

my command is completely messed up and shows every escaped `"` character and output looks like

```
  "properties": {
    "tags": {
      "\"cost_center\"": "\"\"",
      "\"department_name\"": "\"DATA",
      "\"deplyment_version\"": "\"1.0.0\"",
      "\"environment\"": "\"PROD",
      "\"incident_management_application_id\"": "\"ServiceNow\"",
      "\"opco\"": "\"PROD",
      "\"owner_email\"": "\"\"",
      "\"primary_email\"": "\"owner@owner.com\"",
      "\"primary_owner\"": "\"Owner",
      "\"project_billing_name\"": "\"DIF\"",
      "\"project_epic\"": "\"\"",
      "\"project_feature\"": "\"\"",
      "\"project_name\"": "\"DIF\"",
      "ANALYTICS\"": "",
      "NEW\"": "",
      "Name\"": "",
      "and": ""
    }
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> tag my Azure resources based on content of json file.

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed Microsoft-Document:

```
$res= Get-Content "Path" 
$answer=az tag update --operation Replace --resource-id "XX" --tags $res
$answer | ft
```

Path- Path of the file or files Location
XX- Resource Id

**y.json:**

```
"primary_email"= "owner@owner.com"
"primary_owner"= "Owner-Name"
"project_billing_name"= "DIF"
"project_epic"= " "
"project_feature"= " "
"project_name"= "DIF"
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**In Azure Portal(Just to check) Output:**

[image]